# Retrieving all data types supported by MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I'm wondering if there is some command that can be used for retrieving all data types supported by the currently installed version of MySQL? Something like "SHOW DATA TYPES" (this is not a valid MySQL command) to get a table containing detailed info about the data types supported. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarification. I don't need to know columns' data types of a table. I want to retrieve all data types supported by MySQL - CHAR, VARCHAR, TINYINT, INT, BIGINT, BLOB, TEXT etc.- so that I can use that info later on for highlighting SQL-code on my website.

Comment: Yes, clearly @Fahim Parkar didn't get it. There is no command that will display that. But check the documentation I showed you in my answer. That'll help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can run from the console the following command:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
```

I have version 5.1 installed so I can check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html) the appropiate documentation on the link "MySQL 5.1 Manual".

Do the same for yours.

Comment: Read the question again Fahim. `retrieving all data types supported by the currently installed version of MySQL`. You provided a way to dispaly info about a table.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar: What query? He's asking `if there is some command that can be used for`. I said `No` and also gave him a way to find that out. You went for a `describe table` and I get a -1 from you?

Comment: And now you run away erasing your answer and your impolite comments but you still left the -1. That's mature [Fahim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1066828) :)